# Deploying own debian package to Launchpad

Tags: deb, packaging, debian

I am trying to generate a *signed* debian package for deployment to Launchpad. I can generate the binary-only build using :

```
dpkg-buildpackage -b -pgpg -kmihaigalos@gmail.com 
dpkg-buildpackage: source package netatmo-indicator
dpkg-buildpackage: source version 0.1-1
dpkg-buildpackage: source distribution xenial
dpkg-buildpackage: source changed by Mihai Galos <mihaigalos@gmail.com>
dpkg-buildpackage: host architecture amd64
 dpkg-source --before-build netatmo-indicator
 fakeroot debian/rules clean
dh clean
   dh_testdir
   dh_auto_clean
   dh_clean
 debian/rules build
dh build
   dh_testdir
   dh_update_autotools_config
   dh_auto_configure
   dh_auto_build
   dh_auto_test
 fakeroot debian/rules binary
dh binary
   dh_testroot
   dh_prep
   dh_auto_install
   dh_install
   dh_installdocs
   dh_installchangelogs
   dh_perl
   dh_link
   dh_strip_nondeterminism
   dh_compress
   dh_fixperms
   dh_installdeb
   dh_gencontrol
dpkg-gencontrol: warning: Depends field of package netatmo-indicator: unknown substitution variable ${python:Depends}
   dh_md5sums
   dh_builddeb
dpkg-deb: building package 'netatmo-indicator' in '../netatmo-indicator_0.1-1_all.deb'.
 dpkg-genchanges -b >../netatmo-indicator_0.1-1_amd64.changes
dpkg-genchanges: binary-only upload (no source code included)
 dpkg-source --after-build netatmo-indicator
dpkg-buildpackage: binary-only upload (no source included)
 signfile netatmo-indicator_0.1-1_amd64.changes

You need a passphrase to unlock the secret key for
user: "Mihai Galos <mihaigalos@gmail.com>"
2048-bit RSA key, ID 174B180D, created 2018-10-26

(done)
```

So far so good, but Launchpad only accepts source-only builds. I thus build with `-S`:

```
dpkg-buildpackage -S -pgpg -kmihaigalos@gmail.com
dpkg-buildpackage: source package netatmo-indicator
dpkg-buildpackage: source version 0.1-1
dpkg-buildpackage: source distribution xenial
dpkg-buildpackage: source changed by Mihai Galos <mihaigalos@gmail.com>
 dpkg-source --before-build netatmo-indicator
 fakeroot debian/rules clean
dh clean
   dh_testdir
   dh_auto_clean
   dh_clean
 dpkg-source -b netatmo-indicator
dpkg-source: error: can't build with source format '3.0 (quilt)': no upstream tarball found at ../netatmo-indicator_0.1.orig.tar.{bz2,gz,lzma,xz}
dpkg-buildpackage: error: dpkg-source -b netatmo-indicator gave error exit status 255
```

my debian/source/format file contains `3.0 (quilt)`.

What could be the problem here?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message you got:

> `dpkg-source: error: can't build with source format '3.0 (quilt)': no upstream tarball found at ../netatmo-indicator_0.1.orig.tar.{bz2,gz,lzma,xz}`

#### Debian packager way

In the normal workflow, packager starts by downloading `*.orig.tar.gz` archive then extracting. So original archive is already in place.

- Debian packages can be split into two kinds: native '`3.0 (native)`' and non-native '`3.0 (quilt)`'.

  They have a slight different way in building. Check [DebianMentorsFaq](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianMentorsFaq#What_is_the_difference_between_a_native_Debian_package_and_a_non-native_package.3F) or [`man dpkg-source`](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/dpkg-dev/dpkg-source.1.en.html).
- Anyway, just create an original source archive in the parent folder with exact naming and using one of the allowed formats. Example: `netatmo-indicator_0.1.orig.tar.gz`

#### Upstream Developer way

- There are other helping tools to build Debian package directly from the source tree without original archive. Look for: `git-buildpackage`, `bzr-builddeb`, ...